PHP filter_input_array - send key name to custom filter with FILTER_CALLBACK
I'm about to rewrite an older PHP system to use filter_input() and filter_input_array() instead of older methods.
Since the system is already cleverly using fieldnames that indicates what kind of value the fields should hold (int_name, str_name, flt_name, date_name and so on), I thought it would be clever if filter_input_array() offered some way of choosing a specific filter based on key name.
Ideally filter_input the whole array in one go, with filter_input_array()
I stumbled across FILTER_CALLBACK which seemed interesting for a short while, until learning that it's not possible to just call the same callback method for any field. We have to manually specify each fieldname. Also, even if it was possible, it seems we can't see what the fieldname actually is, in a callback method. Only the value of the field is sent to the callback function. And that of course makes it impossible to choose an action based on fieldname.
The docs state that I can pick a single filter-type for filter_input_array if I want to use the same filter for all fields in the array. However, this does not apply to FILTER_CALLBACK, I assume because I also need to provide the name of the callback method, which I can't do with that approach(?).
So, after lots of fruitless searching I'm here asking: Is there any way to do what I want to do: Filter the whole array in one go with something along the lines of:
$filtered_values = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_CALLBACK, "mycustomfilter");
And have mycustomfilter() receive both keyname and value of the array elements.

No, you can not add behavior to the exisiting functions. Why don't you implement your own filter_input_array_with_callback()?

Even if such a thing existed you might choose not to do it this way. A hacker could spot what you're doing and introduce new field names to see how your code reacts. It might be a way to introduce values into your code you don't expect, or make it crash in some way. Given that you didn't spot this weakness in your idea, there might be other weaknesses in your code that can be exploited. Basically the field names will become another form of user input and this needs filtering as well.

I don't see any logic in your perspective KIKO. Obviously any field type not included in my list will simply be excluded. In other words, it's no different than any other kind of form. A hacker can always add fields and see what the code will do. This is no more vulnerable than any other solution.

@MarkusZeller Technically, he can add / edit an existing function behavior, check out the uopz extension.

"Since the system is already cleverly using fieldnames ..." sorry but this is not a cleaver way, this maybe a clever for you or in the context of your system, but not in general, while the PHP function should be able to handle the general use case, I mean it is a kind of opinion based to define what is clever and what is not, the algorithms should not be an opinion based thing.

@hassan It is hacking with an extension, so you have no native way. Doing that may crash existing behavior and should not be considered as a suggestion.

@MarkusZeller yes, that's right, I mean that there is a way to do this after all, not necessary to be a right way.

Although, this is not a great idea to rely on the user input, specially when it comes to the validation, you can go through this by various ways.
1- as mentioned in the comments, implement your own filter_input.
2- go and hack the input_filter behavior using uopz extension.
3- go around the current input_filter_array implementation by creating a custom rule options, something like following:
function cb($value, $key) {
    // Based on the $key prefix, do some validation on the $value
    return $key . ' >> ' . $value;
}

$rules = [];
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    $rules[$key] = [
        'filter' => FILTER_CALLBACK,
        'options' => function () use ($key, $value) {
            return cb($value, $key);
        }
    ];
}

$z = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, $rules);


As far as I understand, the whole point with using filter_input / filter_input_array is to avoid "accessing $_GET and $_POST directly". Using this approach will still access $_GET directly. If I'm "allowed" to do that, I can easily find solutions. But I'm trying to "stick to the rules".

Why to avoid using & accessing $_GET & $_POST? the point of going with filter_input instead of directly access $_GET is that you will be enforced to validate or sanitize the input, while with $_GET you can go without any kind of validation
